# Unwrapping optional @State array to use in ForEach

Tags: swift

I'm trying to unwrap an optional @State variable to be used in ForEach, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it properly and it's throwing me error. Any insights on where the issue is?

```
import SwiftUI

struct CommentView: View {
    
    @State private var commentsQuery: Comments?
    var postPublicId: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
          
            if let commentsQuery = Binding($commentsQuery) {
                ForEach(commentsQuery.comments, id: \.id) { comment in
                    CommentCellView(comment: comment)
                    
                }
            }
        }
         //.onAppear (Reach out to server for data)
    }
}
```

FYI Here are the struct objects

```
struct Comments: Codable {
    var comments: [Comment]?
    var next: String?
}

struct Comment: Codable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let body: String
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Counterquestion: Why is `commentsQuery` optional at all? The design of SwiftUI encourages you to avoid optionals as much as possible especially in the *source of truth*.

Comment: It's fetched from the server, so the value can return null

Comment: Then use an enum with associated values and show an error message to the user if the value is null or a server error occurred. It's much more efficient than the *pyramid-of-safely-unwrapping-optionals*. Please have a look at https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/handling-loading-states-in-swiftui/.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to make the @State property non-optional, then the code becomes easier to implement

```
struct CommentView: View {
    @State private var commentsQuery: Comments
    var postPublicId: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($commentsQuery.comments, id: \.id) { $comment in
                CommentCellView(comment: $comment)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in CommentCellView you use @Binding, something like

```
struct CommentCellView: View {
    @Binding var comment: Comment
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Title", text: $comment.title)
            TextField("Body", text: $comment.body)
        }
    }
}
```

I also made some changes to the model types for this to work

```
struct Comments: Codable {
    var comments: [Comment] = [] 
    var next: String?
}

struct Comment: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    var title: String
    var body: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're making a binding here. You can unwrap like it was a normal variable, which is supported in view builders now:

```swift
if let commentsQuery {
    ForEach(commentsQuery.comments ...
}
```

Or provide a default value if you don't want an extra level of nesting:

```swift
ForEach(commentsQuery?.comments ?? [] ...
```

Also, make `Comment` conform to `Identifiable` then you don't need to specify the ID.